# Discord.py avatar tobytes raise error image

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to get a random avatar, if I don't resize it, I can use it without any problem, but when I resize it gives me an unsupported type error.

**My Code**:

```
resp = requests.get('https://www.generatormix.com/random-female-celebrities', stream=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
elements = soup.find_all("img", class_="thumbnail")
rand_photo = elements[:6][random.randint(0, 5)]['data-src']
rand_photo = requests.get(rand_photo)
pilImage = Image.open(BytesIO(rand_photo.content))
pilImage = pilImage.resize((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS)
await client.user.edit(password=str(data.get()['Settings']['password']), avatar=pilImage.tobytes())
```

**Error output**:

```
C:\Users\fatih\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Python\discord-project\main.py:1204: DeprecationWarning: ANTIALIAS is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use LANCZOS or Resampling.LANCZOS instead.
  pilImage = pilImage.resize((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS).convert("RGBA")
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fatih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fatih\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Python\discord reklam-project\main.py", line 1205, in on_ready
    await client.user.edit(password=str(data.get()['Settings']['password']), avatar=pilImage.tobytes())
  File "C:\Users\fatih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\user.py", line 478, in edit
    avatar = _bytes_to_base64_data(avatar_bytes)
  File "C:\Users\fatih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 323, in _bytes_to_base64_data
    mime = _get_mime_type_for_image(data)
  File "C:\Users\fatih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 319, in _get_mime_type_for_image
    raise InvalidArgument('Unsupported image type given')
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: Unsupported image type given
```

Comment: Why did you delete your old question (which was identical, word to word) and create a new one?

Comment: I entered the wrong tags and got very little reaction

Comment: You can edit questions. Also you have the same tags. For the future, please don't spam the site.

Comment: yes you're right it's my fault I'll be more careful next time

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text. Copy-paste directly into the post and format it using a [code block]. Also properly indent the code you post.

Comment: What type of image are you editing to? png? jpeg?

Comment: I'm editing for a jpeg image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```py
# ...
pil_image = pil_image.resize((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS)
bytes_image = BytesIO()
pil_image.save(bytes_image, format='JPEG')
await client.user.edit(
    password=str(data.get()['Settings']['password']), 
    avatar=bytes_image.getvalue()
)
```

Comment: Does pil_image.save download the photo ?

Comment: In this case not. I'm saving the content to a bytes object